# Scientific evidence about studying and learning strategies

Tags: learning

As many of you, I'm trying to improve learning strategies. I've tried mnemotecnics, breaking study-time into small chunks, and going for a walk when stuck with maths, physics or chemistry problems.

After seeing [Study Less Study Smart](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IlU-zDU6aQ0) by Marty Lobdell I got more interested in the subject. He states these strategies:

1. Study break
2. Reward system
3. Dedicated study area (Behavior Reinforcement)
4. Rote memorization vs. Active learning
5. Sleeping (REM  Sleep)
6. Taking notes (and expanding those)
7. Study from books (SQ3R = Survey,  Question,  Read,  Recite,  Review
8. Mnemonics (Acronyms, Coin Sayings, Interactive Images)

**Question**

I am not really aware which learning strategies are confirmed by experiments, so what I'm looking for is the following:

Where can I start to read simple papers, reviews or essays on the science about learning and studying strategies?

Comment: One's diet may also be important. See Steven Gundry's *The Plant Paradox* for an interesting diet to consider. Although this diet is primarily focused on disease prevention, brain fog is part of it which could prevent one from studying well.

Comment: @FrankHubeny wow, cool. Thanks...

Comment: @Fizz not because this is a request for studies, that's the difference. Then I'll read them.

Comment: @Schopenhauer [All questions on this site should be considered as requests for studies](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16/21). This is a scientific stack. Also, that question asked: _"I want to know if there is some kind of research, evidence(strong or weak), that there are more effective approaches to learning a specific field at a much faster pace."_ Was [the _review paper_ Fizz mentioned in the answer there](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/a/20554/21) (thus encompassing _many_ studies) not a useful answer? If so, why not?

Comment: I can reopen in case you can clarify how or why your question is different (you can edit). That said, I prefer the way you phrased this question over the duplicate question, so alternatively you can simply ask a new more specific question so that this one can stay behind as a resource for others.

Comment: @StevenJeuris thanks, I'll see what can I do!